# How to create move box2d body like Lift (body can move UP and Down automatically)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

Here i am making a small game in box2d. In that i want a body with automatically move up and down like Lift . 
i tried this code using this code body can moving when i touch. but i want move y position 0 to 480 and again reverse 480 to 0.

```
enter code here

//Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Add a new body/atlas sprite at the touched location
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

        //[self addNewSpriteWithCoords: location];
        b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0, 20);
        _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _body->GetPosition());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the joints section here:

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

The prismatic joint might be good for this. Also you may want to consider a kinematic body for this if it is supposed to be a lift/elevator but really that depends on what you are hoping to achieve. Definitely check out the difference between kinematic and dynamic (and static) bodies in the bodies section.